# PHP: String name for field value in a multi-dimentional array

Tags: php, arrays, string, variables, post

I have the name for of a form field that looks like `formname[fieldname][value]`. After some processing the text field is inside of an array that looks like this:

```
    $formname = array (
        'something' => array(),
        'somethingelse' => array(),
        'fieldname' => array (
            'type' => 'text',
            'value' => 'The string I want to retrieve.'
        )
    )
```

Is there a simple way to use that string name to get the value out of that array?

I've tried using the string as a "variable variable" (i.e. `$$formname[fieldname][value]`) but it didn't work with the array.

Comment: `$formname['fieldname']['value']` is all you need. going var-var, means you'd be trying to access a variable NAMED `The string I want to retrieve`, which certainly won't exist.

Comment: Use quotes: `$formname['fieldname]['value']`

Comment: The string field name and array structure are given to me by the system I'm working with. I'll probably have to write a preg_replace to add quotes.

Comment: Maybe you ask about that `foreach($formname['fieldname'] as $key => $value) echo $key . " => " . $value;`

Comment: That's a good point splash58, I'm now iterating through the array and matching it up to the string name to get the value I need. Thanks for the inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the name of the form in a variable, like `$myForm = 'contactForm';` and you create dinamically the variable $contactForm with all the data inside you can use that to access the data you need like:

```
$contactForm = ["has" => ["dogs" => "perros"]];

$formName = "contactForm";
$key1 = "has";
$key2 = "dogs";
echo $$formName[$key1][$key2]; // Output Perros.
```

If you want to iterate over the values you have several ways, for, while, foreach... here is one example:

```
foreach($$formName as $key => $value {
    echo $key . ": ". $value; //be carefull, this value could be an array.
}
```

If you know what you are doing its ok, otherwise I do not recommend dinamically created variables. Are incompatible with HHVM, and could be tricky and untraceable.

Comment: You may want to add in your answer, at least, a little explanation on how and why this code snippet does answer the OP question, as an for the OP as well as for any future reader of you answer having the same issue.